# Let $a_1/b_1,...,a_n/b_n\in (\alpha,\beta)\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $b_1,...,b_n>0$. Prove that $\dfrac{(a_1+...+a_n)}{(b_1+...+b_n)}\in (\alpha,\beta)$

Tags: real-analysis

I tried to prove that $\frac{a_1+a_2}{b_1+b_2}$ is limited by some $(a,b)\subset(\alpha,\beta)$ but i can't conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Proposition.** *Let $\frac{a_i}{b_i} \in (\alpha,\beta)$ and $t_i,b_i>0$ ($i=1,...,n$), then*
>   $$\frac{t_1a_1 + \cdots + t_na_n}{t_1b_1 + \cdots + t_nb_n} \in (\alpha,\beta).$$

*Sketch of the proof.* For each $i$,
$$\alpha < \frac{t_ia_i}{t_ib_i} < \beta.$$
Since $t_ib_i > 0$, we get
$$\alpha t_ib_i < t_ia_i < \beta t_ib_i.$$
Now apply the $\sum_1^n$ on the previous inequality. Then I think you can conclude by taking $t_i = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant to ask is to show that the ratio of the sums belongs to $(\alpha,\beta)$ as well. And this is true, since you can write the ratio of the sums as a convex linear combination of the individual ratios.

Comment: Yeah, it's in $(\alpha,\beta)$, i make a mistake and put $\mathbb{R}$ instead $(\alpha,\beta)$ in the end of question.

Comment: Do you understand my answer? (See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help, i had not thought on that way to prove this proposition.